# Confused in Understanding the flow of execution in Python Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder how is `class C` being executed in this code flow
When none of the flow calls it.

```
class A:
        def fun1(self):
            print("This is class A")


class B(A):
    def fun2(self):
        super().fun1()
        print("This is class B")


class C(A):
    def fun1(self):
        super().fun1()
        print("This is class C")


class D(B, C):
    def fun1(self):
        self.fun2()
        print("This is class D")


obj = D()
obj.fun1()

"""
# Result of this code is 
This is class A
This is class C
This is class B
This is class D
"""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) used is a [C3 linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) algorithm, and `super` itself uses this MRO. The resolution for a type is obtained with the `mro()` method, and cached in the `__mro__` attribute:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object)
>>> D.mro()
[__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object]
```

Since you call print *after* calling super, you'll see the reverse of this, i.e. *A -> C -> B -> D*.

> I wonder how is class C being executed in this code flow when none of the flow calls it.

`D.fun2` doesn't exist, so `obj.fun2()` gets resolved (via the MRO) on `B` instead:

```
>>> obj = D()
>>> obj.fun2
<bound method B.fun2 of <__main__.D object at 0x7fffe89a3cd0>>
```

Then in `B.fun2`, the `C.fun1` gets called here:

```
class B(A):
    def fun2(self):
        super().fun1()  # <-- this resolves to C.fun1, not A.fun1!
        print("This is class B")
```

`C.fun1` is called since it's D's MRO which is active here, not B's, because the `type(self) is D`. Note that `super()` does not always resolve on the parent class, it can be resolved on a sibling class like in your example. Python's implementation was more or less lifted from another programming language called [Dylan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dylan_(programming_language)), where `super` was named [`next-method`](https://opendylan.org/documentation/intro-dylan/objects.html), a less confusing name in my opinion.